# TypeError: a is undefined + Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using **jQuery 1.11.1** and I am getting this error in Firebug's console:

`TypeError: a is undefined`

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined 
m.extend.each 
(anonymous function) 
j 
k.fireWith 
x 
b
```

in Google Chrome's console.

Here is the screenshot from the console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQqNq.jpg

My javascript code is this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready( function () {

            $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();


                var formData = new FormData();

                formData.append('username', $('#username').val());
                formData.append('email', $('#email').val());
                formData.append('password', $('#password').val());
                formData.append('password_confirmation', $('#password_confirmation').val());

                $.ajax({
                    url:         'registration',
                    method:      'post',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache:       false,
                    dataType:    'json',
                    data:        formData,
                    beforeSend: function()
                        {
                            $('#ajax-loading').show();
                            $(".validation-error-inline").hide();
                        }
                    })
                    .done(function(data) {

                        if (data.validation_failed == 1)
                        {
                            var arr = data.errors;

                            $.each(arr, function(index, value)
                            {
                                if (value.length != 0)
                                {
                                    $("#" + index).after('<span class="text-error validation-error-inline">' + value + '</span>');
                                }
                            });
                            $('#ajax-loading').hide();

                        }


                    })
                    .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert('No response from server');
                    });
                    return false;

            });
        });
    </script>
```

And I find out that when I comment out this part:

```
$.each(arr, function(index, value)
    {
        if (value.length != 0)
        {
            $("#" + index).after('<span class="text-error validation-error-inline">' + value + '</span>');
        }
});
$('#ajax-loading').hide();
```

Then I get no error. Why is `$.each` causing the problem?

Any idea how to fix that?

Btw. I am using Laravel and

Comment: `arr` is not a collection, i.e. neither an array or an object in this case.

Comment: means that ``value`` dont have length property

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the line after `.done` and look at `data` - probably, it does not have the `errors` property and thus you can't iterate over the errors.

Comment: here is a screenshot from the console maybe it helps http://imgur.com/xCHrAm1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
var arr = data.errors;
```

To:

```
var arr = data.error;
```

And:

```
$("#" + index).after('<span class="text-error validation-error-inline">' + value + '</span>');
```

To:

```
$("#" + index).after('<span class="text-error validation-error-inline">' + value[0] + '</span>');
```